# Why do we use RMS current as the input current for calculating efficiency of half-wave rectifier?

Tags: rectifier, efficiency, rms

V<sub>i</sub> = V<sub>m</sub>sin(ωt)

I<sub>m</sub> = <sup>V<sub>m</sub></sup>⁄<sub>R</sub> = maximum amplitude of dc current
I<sub>rms</sub> = <sup>I<sub>m</sub></sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>
I<sub>avg</sub> = <sup>I<sub>m</sub></sup>⁄<sub>π</sub>
η = <sup>P<sub>dc</sub></sup>⁄<sub>P<sub>i</sub></sub> = efficiency

P<sub>i</sub> = (I<sub>avg</sub>)<sup>2</sup>R

P<sub>dc</sub> = (I<sub>rms</sub>)<sup>2</sup>R

Since the negative portion of the wave is not involved :

- Why use RMS of current for input power?
- Where is the power being lost?
- Why?

Just to add some context please see this [link.](https://www.electrical4u.com/half-wave-rectifiers/#Efficiency-of-Half-Wave-Rectifier)

Comment: Where did the formulas come from i.e. can we have some context please? What does \$I_m\$ represent?

Comment: @Andyaka I added some, is this enough, I got this from "Electronic Devices and Circuit Theory Prentice Hall" 11th edition.
I am not sure I can post pictures from there.
But I did not see the concept of efficiency in that book. I don't know if it's there.

Comment: $$I_{RMS} = \dfrac{I_m}{\sqrt2}\text{.... and not 2}$$ And the \$I_{AVE}\$ is for half a cycle of the sinewave.

Comment: @Andyaka https://www.electrical4u.com/half-wave-rectifiers/#RMS-value-of-Half-Wave-Rectifier

Comment: OK you are talking about the RMS of the rectified waveform. You know, a picture would have helped.

Comment: Link now goes directly to the section on the efficiency of the half wave rectifier.

Comment: @Andyaka You are correct. But afaik I can't get those without permission. So I gave the link in the description too :)

Comment: Because before the bridge you have an alternating current regime, and afterwards you have DC. Even if only one alternance works before the bridge, that is just one case out of many. You can't just use the average in this case and then the RMS in the case of full-wave rectifiers.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen are you saying that sometimes even in this setup some negative component of current flows?

Comment: @Adcock I'm saying that you should treat AC regimes as AC regimes, and DC regimes as DC regimes. Do not mix them, no matter what. Even if you only have one alternance drawing current and the other not.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Okay okay. But is there experimental data to back this?

Comment: @Adcock Would a whole theory of electrical circuits do?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Okay. Give me that instead.